# How do I know if ECM happens in a foreign language?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, cases, theta-role

I have learned about ECM and how it works within the English language, but I don't understand it thoroughly. How would we be able to decide whether a language has ECM?

Comment: ECM being the thing where, when an infinitive is used as a direct object, the subject of that infinitive can be marked as an object instead of a subject? (The example I always think of is "search your feelings, you know **it** to be true", but that's not a great example because "it" doesn't show a difference between subject and object case.)

Comment: What does "ECM" stand for? Giving just an acronym is not good practice in a question when you can use the full name. Perhaps you're talking about Subject Raising, like _him_ in _They expect him to take responsibility for it_ or _there_ in  _There seems to be a problem_?